# PHP how to stop email sending out from localhost

Tags: php, email, xampp

My question is bit reverse than all on the internet. I have used XAMPP over a long period. When I updated my `xampp` to `1.8.3` it started to send emails from my `localhost`. so I moved back to `1.8.1`,

recently I had to update to `1.8.3` due to some requirements. PHP version is `5.5.15`. It now started to send emails again.

My question is, How can I disable sending emails. and Can I do it on per project base, my application is having actual data on my `localhost`, and when ever QA team or other developers try updating the orders for a client, my client gets the email alerts, and this is causing lots of trouble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use

```
ini_set('disable_functions','mail');
```

Or set `disable_functions=mail` in your php.ini

Comment: it didnt worked in mac, also I havnt checked but will I need to disable PHPMailer SMTP send functions as well